# ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT: Cannot set cookie

Tags: node.js, typescript, cookies, response, firebase-admin

this is my code

```
import { Request, Response } from "express";
import { database } from "firebase-admin";

async function updatereAccessToken(
  req: Request,
  res: Response,
  db: database.Database
) {
  try {

    await db
      .ref(
        `/token/${"-MUQK0wGmrjPVBdFH7gr"}/${"90417abf-b085-4072-b4ec-f009b5fe4016"}`
      )
      .set("90417abf-b085-4072-b4ec-f009b5fe4016");

    
    await db
      .ref(
        `/token/${"-MUQK0wGmrjPVBdFH7gr"}/${"90417abf-b085-4072-b4ec-f009b5fe4016"}`
      )
      .set("90417abf-b085-4072-b4ec-f009b5fe4016");

//comments

    res.cookie("act", "tokenAuth.accessToken", {
      httpOnly: true,
      sameSite: "lax",
    });

    res.cookie("ret", "tokenAuth.refreshToken", {
      httpOnly: true,
      sameSite: "lax",
    });

    return "currentUser";
  } catch (error) {}
}
```

Code works before comment.then i get error

> [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
> at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:558:11)

Split the code into two parts

***1***

```
    await db
      .ref(
        `/token/${"-MUQK0wGmrjPVBdFH7gr"}/${"90417abf-b085-4072-b4ec-f009b5fe4016"}`
      )
      .set("90417abf-b085-4072-b4ec-f009b5fe4016");

    
    await db
      .ref(
        `/token/${"-MUQK0wGmrjPVBdFH7gr"}/${"90417abf-b085-4072-b4ec-f009b5fe4016"}`
      )
      .set("90417abf-b085-4072-b4ec-f009b5fe4016");
```

***2***

```
res.cookie("act", "tokenAuth.accessToken", {
          httpOnly: true,
          sameSite: "lax",
        });
    
        res.cookie("ret", "tokenAuth.refreshToken", {
          httpOnly: true,
          sameSite: "lax",
        });
```

These two parts of the code work separately, but not together. What is the reason ?.

Answer (score 0):

`Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]` is an interesting error that is fired up when a server tries to send more than one response to a client. What this means is that for a given client request, the server previously sent a response (either a success response with the resource requested or an error response for a bad request) back to the client and now is unexpectedly trying to send another response.
That's what explains why they work seperately and not together.